# NamedQuery: IllegalArgumentException (Query not found) after externalizing entities

Tags: jpa, ejb, named-query

I have successfully used `javax.persistence.NamedQuery` in combination with JPA2. The named queries are defined at the top of the entity class files, and are used from Stateless EJBs (entity facade).

Now I had to extract the entity class files into a separate Jar file (so we can use them from a Google Web Toolkit project). Obviously I still incude the jar, but now the facade bean does not find the query anymore:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NamedQuery of name: Store.findByExternalId not found.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getDatabaseQueryInternal(EJBQueryImpl.java:576)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createNamedQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1004)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.createNamedQuery(EntityManagerWrapper.java:533)
    at com.skalio.bonusapp.server.StoreFacade.getByExternalId(StoreFacade.java:43)
    ...
```

What is the problem here? Can I not define NamedQueries in an external Jar?

I just found this [link](http://jdevelopment.nl/put-named-queries-jpa/), suggesting to put the NamedQueries in XML files, not as annotations in the entity files. This could be an idea to solve my problem, but doesn't answer my question... ;)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The solution is to specify the classes containing JPA Entities in the persistence.xml file:

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="bonusAppServerPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/someDB</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.skalio.bonusapp.core.Store</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Background is that JPA needs to be told where to scan for annotations. The other option is to use the `<jar-file></jar-file>` node.

Comment: You can use the complete package scan rather than giving each class name like below
`<property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />`