# Why am I restricted to placing NamedQuery annotation only on an entity class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

A logical place to place named query annotations is on a data access class, one that deals the logic of saving, retrieving etc. data for an entity.

However, Hibernate throws an exception "No query defined for that name" if I place a NamedQuery annotation on a class which is not marked with @Entity.

Why does Hibernate or JPA limit named queries to be only placed on entities? Could it be a future feature?

There are a few crude workarounds such as using an
[empty entity to hold queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14158254/754300), which makes me think that it would useful to not be restricted like this. I know I can use an XML config, but named queries on non-entities would still be useful.

Comment: Some JPA implementations allow them to be on any class, just that the JPA spec and your selected implementation don't

Comment: What if you add them to the `persistence.xml` as a managed class?

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [JpaRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html) you can see that you can declare them in other way:

**Annotation based named query configuration**

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "User.findByEmailAddress",
  query = "select u from User u where u.emailAddress = ?1")
public class User {

}
```

**Declare query at the query method using @Query**

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  @Query("select u from User u where u.emailAddress = ?1")
  User findByEmailAddress(String emailAddress);
}
```

Comment: Is this a Spring specific feature? I don't think it is part of JPA or Hibernate.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Do you know any solution if one is not using Spring?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602397/how-do-i-externalize-named-queries-in-a-hibernate-annotations-app
You can add the queries to the `package-info.java` file.